# Arguing the moral point with no evidence but ideas

Tags: word-choice

I'm trying to write a paper about US Invasion in Iraq is unjust morally, militarily, and legally. I can't think of words to explain when I'm trying to explain that I have moral "evidence" or ideas from the book that will help to support my moral argument. It is technically not evidence, but what word should I use to accurately explain it like evidence?

Comment: Let's say you were to use the word evidence. What would the sentence you write look like? I'm not really getting what you want a word like this for.

Comment: Why not stick with _moral arguments_?

Comment: Ok, the introductory paragraph says that I found a number of evidences that supports each three points of our argument about injustice morally, militarily, and legally. I have excepts from the book that gives a good moral point. It's not technically an evidence but it will help to support my argument. I hope that's clear enough or do you want me to explain more?

Comment: I guess moral arguments sounds suffice and to-the-point. I'll try that. Thanks

Comment: Are you saying that there are moral, military and legal principles well established in a book or books that you contend support your argument? Perhaps the word you're looking for is a citation.

Comment: I would avoid putting *evidence* in quotations. This suggests that what you have doesn't amount to evidence and weakens your argument. Depending where you derive your morality from, *moral arguments* are indeed based on evidence, just of a slightly different sort than, say, military arguments. For example, if your morals say "do not kill" than your evidence against the war would be the fact that people were killed.

Comment: How about "moral, military and legal theories or principles"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An *argument* normally involves two opposing positions. If the argument is about *factual* matters, it's likely one or both positions can be either strengthened or weakened by ***evidence*** (as to which facts are true or false).

Thus, *the US should not have invaded Iraq* can be supported by facts (Iraq had nothing to do with 9/11, Iraquis are worse off now than under Saddam Hussein, they never had any WMD, etc.)

If the argument involves opposing *moral* positions, "facts" aren't necessarily relevant. A sound moral argument is based on ***principles*** (any use of military force is wrong, nations should not interfere in the internal politics of other nations, etc.).